# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'findAncestorStateOfType'

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I am still fairly new to flutter and flame but I am working on a game where I need to able to pass BuilerContext context inside of a class that extends BaseGame, I am currently using a method that adds a component that is a widget to the screen called "addWidgetOverlay". I know that this error is usually caused when BuilderContext context is not called inside of a widget but I am not entirely sure where that would be being my class extends BaseGame and not a stateful or stateless widget. Thanks in advance!

```
import 'package:flame/components/parallax_component.dart';
import 'package:flame/components/text_component.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'gamesfdafdsafdsa.dart';


class NewMenu extends BaseGame with HasWidgetsOverlay {

  final SharedPreferences storage;
  TextComponent _text;
  ParallaxComponent _parallaxComponent;
  // BuildContext context;
  NewMenu(this.storage, BuildContext context) {



    // TEMP BACKGROUND
    _parallaxComponent = ParallaxComponent([
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0010_1.png'),
    ], baseSpeed: Offset(100, 0), layerDelta: Offset(20, 0));


// ADDS THE PLAY BUTTON
    addWidgetOverlay('Play Button',
    Center(
      child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => GamePlay(),
              ),
            );
          },       child: Text('Play')),
    ),
    );

    // PARALLAX COMPONENT
    add(_parallaxComponent);

    // HIGHSCORE TEXT
    _text = TextComponent('${storage.getInt('highscore') ?? 0}');
    add(_text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post more of the stack trace and the version of Flame that you are using.

Comment: I am currently running flame: ^0.29.4 and the error message that I got was NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'findAncestorStateOfType'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a separate class that extends a stateful widget and redid the entire main menu by using the Future builder widget to help display the stored value in my shared preferences. I am still not 100% sure on how to navigate between screens with the class extending BaseGame so I would recommend just using a stateful widget.

Comment: It might help you if you use `1.0.0-releasecandidate.11` instead, because then you can use the `GameWidget` instead.